# onClickListiner not working

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

```
   <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/comment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="271dp">

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Comment"
        android:id="@+id/comment_add"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="253dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:id="@+id/comment_text"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:editable="true"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="218dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom">

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Comment"
            android:id="@+id/comment_add"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="253dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:id="@+id/comment_text"
            android:layout_gravity="left|bottom" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

and the framelayout is contained with relative layout , anyway in the activity code :

```
addComment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.comment_add);
        txtComment = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.comment_text);
addComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addTheComment();

            }
        });
  public void addTheComment() {


        Meal meal=new Meal();

      if(txtComment.getText().toString()!=null){
            meal.setComment(txtComment.getText().toString());
           Toast.makeText(this ,"adding the comment..." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
       }else{
            Toast.makeText(this ,"the comment field is empty" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
       }

    }
```

I imported android view and then as you can see I did a setonclicklistiner and then addthecomment() method in the activity , I am trying to get the text from the edittext and store it into the Meal Class (Parse.com) , but not getting anything when I press the button in the emulator , like the onclick itself is working but nothing happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `addthecomment()` you want to show Toast message according to condition. but message is not visible to user because you forget to call `Toast.show()`. do it as:

```
   if(txtComment.getText().toString()!=null){
        ....
       Toast.makeText(this ,"adding the comment..." ,
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }else{
        Toast.makeText(this ,"the comment field is empty" , 
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
```